# How to display date in Jtable with the date value only?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I insert date into database by the following code

```
String sql = "Insert Into Purchase (Purchase_ID, Purchase_Date) values (?,Date())";
```

and yes, my database store the value with the current date only

But when I retrieve the Purchase Date from my database into JTable, the result display the date when I insert and with the time 00:00:00:00.

How can I want to display the result with the date only?

Answer (score 2):

Use a SimpleDateFormat. For instance:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String s = format.format(yourDate);
```

Comment: yeah..but same..i retrieve data show in table is date and time with 00:00:00:00
Maybe because I use select * from my database table?

Comment: @Q123Q if this doesn't help (as it should) show an SSCCE demonstrating the problem